# Logitech k360 Remapping the next/previous keys on top left

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Logitech k360 keyboard and I'd like to remap the previous track/next track so that when I'm watching a Youtube video while doing other things, I can skip back/forward without clicking the focus on the video window.  Currently I have to select the youtube window, which pauses the video, then use left or right arrow to rewind/fast forward 5 seconds then restart the video then click back to my other windows.  I can pause using the center hotkey without moving focus but not rewind.
Setpoint seems to be....  somewhat less than quite right.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Or is a new keyboard in my future?

Comment: https://www.logitech.com/en-us/software/logi-options-plus.html